# Erro "Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '@P1'." aparece quando passo um parâmetro que será uma nova coluna do SELECT

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tenho um código SQL que conversa com meu banco através de PDO numa função PHP que possui apenas 1 parâmetro (que às vezes virá vazio, que será nos casos que não quero que essa linha seja exibida). Eu percebi que, nas vezes em que o parâmetro `$fciQtde` é uma string iniciando com vírgula (assim: `" ,FCI.Quantidade AS 'qtde'"`), a consulta me retorna o seguinte erro:

*Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '@P1'.*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não há nenhuma variável `@P1` na minha query. Quando faço o código manualmente no SQL Server já com `",FCI.Quantidade AS 'qtde'"`, ele roda normalzinho, porém pelo PHP me retorna esse erro acima.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Meu código:

```
public function getAllForecast($fciQtde) {
    $con = new Conexao();
    $con = $con->conectar();
    try {
        $con->beginTransaction();
        $sql = "SELECT
                    DISTINCT PF.CodigoProduto AS 'prod_id'
                    ,PF.Descricao AS 'nome'
                    :fci_qtde
                FROM
                    ForeCast AS FC
                    INNER JOIN ForeCast_itens AS FCI ON FC.CodigoFC = FCI.Cod_FC
                    INNER JOIN ProdutoFinal AS PF ON FCI.Cod_Produto = PF.CodigoProduto AND PF.EmLinha = 1
                WHERE
                    FCI.Quantidade <> 0 AND PF.Inativo = 0
                ";
        
        $busca = $con->prepare($sql);

        $busca->bindParam(":fci_qtde", $fciQtde, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $busca->execute();
        $resultado = $busca->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $busca->closeCursor();
    
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex;
    }
    
    return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: Não traduza mensagens de erro, coloque elas integralmente. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/3635) e o [mcve].

Comment: parâmetros com `bindParam` são usados no `where`, se pretente usar no nomes de colunas dinamicamente, deve montar a query dinamimente tamém não usando `bindParam`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mas o erro está realmente vindo em pt-br, eu não estou traduzindo. Vou acrescentar o print do erro que estou exibindo na view com o `print_r()`.

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu não sabia que `bindParam()` era só para `WHERE`. Um operador ternário dentro da string `$sql` deve resolver, então (embora não sei se isso é uma boa prática). Obrigado pela informação.

Comment: Entendo, agora leia e compreenda o [mcve], então basta [edit] a pergunta conforme as orientações do link, para que possamos reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado vou ler novamente.